# Check if String can be converted to a given type in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have to validate user input data and ensure a string value is convertible to a type specified at run-time.  I don't necessarily need to do the actual conversion, just test to make sure the input value is valid.  I haven't found a built in class or method that will perform this type of evaluation, but if I am missing one, please let me know.  I'm working with C#4.0, if there is any version specific solutions available.

The method only has to deal with the "standard" types (built-in value data types plus String).  The only custom type I would need to evaluate is specific enum types that are defined in the library.

I have 2 solutions I'm currently weighing, but neither is perfect, so I was hoping there was a 3rd option (or something built into the framework that I missed).  I am heavily leaning towards Solution #2 since using the try-catch in Solution #1 just seems wrong.

**Solution 1**: `Convert.ChangeType()` with try/catch

```
public Boolean CheckType(String value, Type type)
{
    try
    {
        var obj = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        return true;
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch(OverflowException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2** if/else chain with Type check and TryParse

```
public Boolean CheckType(String value, Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(String))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Boolean))
    {
        Boolean b;
        return Boolean.TryParse(value, out b); 
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Int32))
    {
        Int32 i;
        return Int32.TryParse(value, out i); 
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Int64))
    {
        Int64 l;
        return Int64.TryParse(value, out l); 
    }
    // similar code to check all other types 
    // (Int16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt16, Byte, SByte, Single, Double, Decimal,
    //  Enum, Char, DateTime)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type evaluation");

}
```

This method may be called several hundred or even a thousand times in a short interval if the input data is seriously messed up or corrupted, so I'm worried that the repeated if/else checks will be a drag on performance (I'm not necessarily trying to optimize at this point, I just want to make sure I'm considering other options).

The other issue I have with both solutions is that both actually convert the string value to a new value of the expected type, and in both cases, I'm swallowing the result.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee I saw the question you linked, but since I am not looking to actually convert the value, just test that it can be converted, I did not think my question was necessarily a duplicate.

Comment: @psubsee2003: the amount of effort to check if something can be converted, to actually converting it, is generally pretty small.

Comment: @Joe I had a feeling that was the case, but because the TryParse methods are so fast without apparent exceptions, I was wondering if there was a built in way to check first before converting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a better solution than either of my initial ideas in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8227304/250725) that was recently asked.

parapura rajkumar was on the right track with the TypeConverter class, but the required exception handling for the `CanConvertFrom` method for non-exceptional events was what I was trying to avoid.

The `TypeConverter.IsValid` method solved my problem, although it is not ideal because the IsValid method is just a wrapper for the `CanConvertFrom` method and the required exception handling.

```
private Boolean CanCovert(String value, Type type)
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
    return converter.IsValid(value);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Consider using the [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) and generic methods. This avoids lots of if statement. Please add your own error handling based on MSDN documentation

```
 class Program
    {
        static T convert<T>(string s)
        {
            var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
            {
                return (T) typeConverter.ConvertFrom(s);
            }

            return default(T);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = convert<int>( "45");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how this solves the original problem of checking a type is valid.  If I pass an invalid value to the converter (for example, "14.1" for an int), it throws a FormatException.  My first solution already does that, so I'm not sure why this is preferable.

Comment: This is preferable because the method is generic and doesn't need a new **if block** for every new type that you add

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer the `TryParse`-way, because exceptions are expensive (performance).

Comment: In the end, I went with this recommendation as the TypeConverter answer required exception handling, which I wanted to avoid.