# Test if string can be converted to other, various type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

(SOLVED) I'm building an application that can create some of its control dynamically, based on some description from XML file.
What I need now is something very similar to TryParse() method: a possibility to check (wihtout throwing/catching exception), if a text in string variable can be converted (or parsed) to a type, which name I have in other variabe (`myType`).
Problem is that `myType` can be any of .NET types: `DateTime, Bool, Double, Int32` etc.

Example:

```
string testStringOk = "123";
string testStringWrong = "hello";
string myType = "System.Int32";

bool test1 = CanCovertTo(testStringOk, myType);      //true
bool test2 = CanCovertTo(testStringWrong, myType);   //false
```

How does `CanCovertTo(string testString, string testType)` function should look like?

The closest I get is following code:

```
private bool CanCovertTo(string testString, string testType)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(testType, null, null);
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);

    converter.ConvertFrom(testString);  //throws exception when wrong type
    return true;
}
```

however, it throws an exception while trying to convert from wrong string, and I prefer not to use `try {} catch()` for that.

---

**Solution:**

```
private bool CanCovertTo(string testString, string testType)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(testType, null, null);
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
    return converter.IsValid(testString);
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer not to use try/catch for that?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a value in a function that is named CanConvert? Can't you just do "return converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))"

Comment: @PVitt: it's just about "best practices", I've read that you should avoid working with exceptions with normal program actions. I believe that's why TryParse() method exists together with Parse(). Honestly, if there is a better method than this, that allows me to do what I need, I prefer that one. :)

Comment: @Grrbrr404: you're right, `CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))` was not necessary in that code. I've modified post.

Comment: Similiar to a question i asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8122604/250725

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check the method [TypeConverter.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tez461eb.aspx), although:

> Starting in .NET Framework version 4, the IsValid method catches exceptions from the CanConvertFrom and ConvertFrom methods. If the input value type causes CanConvertFrom to return false, or if the input value causes ConvertFrom to raise an exception, the IsValid method returns false.

That means that if you don not use the try...catch by yourself you are going to convert twice the value.

Comment: Great answer.  This actually solves a problem in a question I asked last week.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of passing in the type as a string you should make use of generics e.g.

```
public bool CanConvert<T>(string data)
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    return converter.IsValid(data);
}
```

**Usage**

```
bool test1 = CanConvert<Int32>("1234"); // true
bool test2 = CanConvert<Int32>("hello"); // false
```

Comment: Generics would require the OP know the type at compile type, which it would appear he does not.

Comment: That **would be perfect**, if I knew the exact type before, or could do something like this: `bool test1 = CanConvert <Type.GetType(myType, null, null)> (testStringOk);` I do not know the type however, it's dynamically read and keep in string vaiable.

Comment: @James: Are you able to use a `Type` object as a Generic Type parameters?  I did not think that was possible.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - It can be done using Reflection, however, what I posted was completely wrong! Removed, been a while since I used Generics so a bit rusty!

Answer (score 0):

If they are just built-in .NET types, you can do the conversion based on a System.TypeCode. You could store the typecode in your XML (or convert your type string to a TypeCode) and do something like:

```
switch (code)
{
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
        bool.TryParse(value, out result);
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int32:
        int.TryParse(value, out result);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've been thinking about it, but there are too many lines for that. :) With TypeConverter.IsValid, it could be done with 3 lines. Thanks anyway :)